# How to convert 1234.5678 into 1234.56 in C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to use

```
        double abc = 1234.5678;
        Console.WriteLine(abc.ToString("N2"));
        Console.ReadKey();
```

but that is yielding

```
1.234,57
```

instead of

```
1234.56
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Looks like you have European numerical notation. What's your locale set to in windows?

Comment: Yes, it is european. And that is giving me headaches also :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Specify the [invariant culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) for formatting:

```
Console.WriteLine(abc.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

It's still going to round it up to 1,234.57 though. It's printing the comma now because you've explicitly said you want the "N" format which includes thousands separators.

If you use "F2" it will give "1234.57":

```
Console.WriteLine(abc.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

I'm not sure the best way to stop it from rounding up...

Comment: Or better yet, specify the exact culture you want.

Comment: The problem is still the same. I don't want any "," or "." in the integer part of the number!

Comment: I mean, that is giving me 1,234.57 instead of the desired 1234.57

Comment: @devoured, then get rid of "N2"

Comment: @devoured elysium: I was just editing for that point - use F2 instead of N2.

Comment: There is absolutely no problem with roundings, I just want to get rid of the . thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    double abc = 1234.5678; 
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", Math.Floor(abc*100)/100 ); 
    Console.ReadKey();
```

//      1234.56

or make your own `Floor()` function

```
    public double Floor(double value, int digits)
    {
        double n = Math.Pow(10, digits);
        return Math.Floor(value * n) / n;
    }
```

Comment: I will assume you tested your code, good work at reading the user's question :-)

Comment: My guess is you want `Truncate` instead of `Floor`.

Comment: I tested the code and it works as expected. `Math.Floor()` works by striping the fractional part of a double.

Comment: jalexiou: `Truncate` works by stripping the fractional part of a number. `Floor` works by rounding down. Try them on a negative number and you'll see the difference.

Comment: @Gabe - I agree, and the original post does not describe how to to handle negatives, so either one is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.Round` like this:

```
double abc = 1234.5678;
double rounded = Math.Round(abc, 2);
Console.WriteLine(rounded);
```

And it will output only two fractional digits.

Comment: Josenator I thought he wanted 1234.56 not 1234.57 I suppose it depends on what he will be using the number for.  He either mistakenly said he wanted 1234.56 in his original question or the comment response was mistaken.

Comment: @Ramhound It's true it will not give the exact result he asked for, I assumed he just wanted to round to 2 digits.